# Entity Framework Core: navigation property based collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections, properties, entity-relationship

Let's say we have the following many-to-many relationship scenario in EF Core with following navigation properties:

```
public class Request{

    public HashSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class User{

    public HashSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

A user may be simply assigned to many requests and a request may have many users.

Now, I would like to extend the functionality so every user is able to flag the requests he is assigned to:

```
public class User{

    public HashSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<long, bool> RequestsFlags { get; set; } //Request ID (long) and Flag (bool)
}
```

This way I can check for which request the flag is set and update the UI accordingly. The problem is that of course these 2 collections would have to always be synchronized with each other.

Is there any way to ensure that custom collection is always in line with navigation property?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration. "Additional data can be stored in the join entity type, but for this it's best to create a bespoke CLR type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the act of flagging a request does not need to be persisted to the UserRequest table, then you could consider adding an unmapped property to the Request entity called "Flagged".

I.e.

```
public class Request
{
    // normal mapped properties.
  
    [NotMapped]
    public bool Flagged { get; set; }
}
```

The limitation here is that it is only relevant to entities that have already been loaded. You cannot use it in EF Linq queries.  If users and requests are projected to view models then this property would best be served in the view model.

If you do need to persist the flagged state to a UserRequest record then you need to introduce the joining entity into the relationship:

```
public class User
{
    // User properties...

    // public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; } = new List<Request>();
    public virtual ICollection<UserRequest> UserRequests { get; set; } = new List<UserRequest();
}
   
public class User
{
    // User properties...

    // public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
    public virtual ICollection<UserRequest> UserRequests { get; set; } = new List<UserRequest();
}

public class UserRequest
{ 
    [Key, ForeignKey("User"), Column(Order=0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Request"), Column(Order=1)]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    public bool Flagged { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

This means changing the relationships between Users and Requests to navigate through UserRequests to get to each other.

I.e. instead of:

```
foreach(var request in user.Requests)
{
    // do stuff..
}
```

becomes..

```
foreach(var userRequest in user.UserRequests)
{
    var request = userRequest.Request;
    // do stuff..
}
```

Comment: FYI the example documentation In EF Core 5 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration shows that you can have both the original navigation and the explicit join entity navigation. I assume all the navigations are optional. So you might have `Request.Users` vs `User.UserRequests`

Comment: Thank you both for explaining this to me, indeed it's a perfect solution to the problem I described.